# Making nhibernate do a join on a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria, criteria-api, queryover

I have the following situation I am am stuck.
I have an entity called ContactAssociation which has(among others) the properties Client and a Contact.
I have to get all the Contacts for a Client that fulfill some condintions.
The conditions are:
Each Client has property BusinessEntities which is a collection of BusinessEntity, each BusinessEntity has a BusinessLevel.
This is the code, I am sure will make this more understandable:

```
link.Session.QueryOver<ContactAssociation>(() => ca)
                                       //.Fetch(asoc => asoc.Client)
                                       .JoinAlias(() => ca.Client, ()=> client)

.Left.JoinQueryOver<BuEntry>(() => client.BuEntries, () => be)
                                       .Where(() => client.ID == clientKey)
                                       .Where(() =>    be.BuLevel.LevelNo > buLevel);
```

Ok so I wrote the thing like this and I keep getting an error that the property BuLevel.LevelNo cannot be found
But it is there in the model

I tried criteria but I saw the same error only it was in NHProfiler instead of Visual Studio and there was a more cryptic error in Visual Studio.
Anyway ...
I eventually solved the problem with a sql query but how should I write the QueryOver and/or Criteria to get the proper results?

Thank you in advance

P.S.

Here is my SQL Query:

```
 careTeamMembers = link.Session.CreateSQLQuery(@"select c.* from ContactAssociation ca
                                inner join Contact c
                                on ca.contactkey = c.contactkey
                                left join ContactBu cb
                                on cb.contactkey = c.contactkey
                                left join BuEntry be
                                on cb.entrykey = be.entrykey
                                left join BuLevel bl
                                on be.levelkey = bl.levelkey
                                where ca.clientkey = :clientkey
                                and bl.levelno > :level")
            .AddEntity(typeof(Contact))
            .SetInt32("clientkey", clientKey)
            .SetInt32("level", buLevel)
            .SetMaxResults(1000)
            .List<Contact>();
```

Comment: What does your SQL query look like? That would likely help us figure out what the desired end result is.

Comment: is BusinessLevel also an entity?

Comment: @Vadim yes business level is an entity

Comment: @cs I have added the SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a join on BULevel

```
link.Session.QueryOver<ContactAssociation>(() => ca)
                                       //.Fetch(asoc => asoc.Client)
                                       .JoinAlias(() => ca.Client, ()=> client)

.Left.JoinQueryOver<BuEntry>(() => client.BuEntries, () => be)
                                       .Where(() => client.ID == clientKey)
                                       .JoinQueryOver<BuLevel>(() => be.BuLevel)
                                       .Where(bu => bu.LevelNo > buLevel);
```

Comment: I got this error: `System.ArgumentException: The value "SL.STAdmin.DAL.ContactAssociation" is not of type "SL.STAdmin.DAL.Contact" and cannot be used in this generic collection.` This is the code I wrote: `ContactAssociation ca = null;
Contact client = null;
BuEntry be = null;
careTeamMembers = link.Session.QueryOver<ContactAssociation>(() => ca).JoinAlias(() => ca.Client, () => client).Left.JoinQueryOver<BuEntry>(() => client.BuEntries, () => be).Where(() => client.ID == clientKey).JoinQueryOver<BuLevel>(() => be.BuLevel).Where(bu => bu.LevelNo > buLevel).Take(1000).List<Contact>();`

Comment: @Para, your query is for ContactAssociations, but you then want it to return Contacts. It won't be able to do that. You can either add a Projection for retrieving the association's Contact, create your criteria from the Contact end, or return a list of ContactAssociations.

Comment: @Para, you can learn more about projections here http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections as for the other approaches, that all depends on your entity structure.